# Is there a way to convert decimal time to a regular time e.g. 5.5=5:30

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I've pulled a large amount of data and put it into a pivot format. It has been requested to display the times in a time value instead of decimal value. The data came in a decimal value and had many rows of decimal values.
Is there any way to convert this without having to manually go and change them with a formula.
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You will need to change the cell contents to do this. The layout of your pivot table will determine how to do this. If the time is in the values section, just add a calculated field ( = `original time value / 24` and display that instead (formatting as `h:mm`). If it is in the Rows section, you'll need to convert the value before creating the Pivot Table.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your decimal time is `5.5`, which you want to convert to `5:30`. This value is in cell `A1`.

1. In cell `B1`, type `=MROUND(A1/24, 1/(24*60))`. This formula will round
   the decimal hours to the nearest minute.
2. Press Enter.
3. Now, let's format `B1` to show time. Right-click on cell `B1` and select
   **Format Cells**.
4. From the **Category** list, choose **Time**.
5. From the **Type** list, choose **13:30**.
6. Press **OK**.

Now, cell `B1` should show `05:30`, which is the conversion of `5.5` decimal hours to time. If you have other cells to convert, just copy the formula in `B1` and paste it into the appropriate cells.

Comment: I have 20 columns of decimal times that's been pivoted, adding in new rows will bloat the workbook and the pivot table. I'm asking if there's a different method besides this one.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, Excel doesn't provide a direct method to do this within the pivot table itself.